# Azure Media Service with CDN and HTTPS

Tags: azure, video, cloud, media, cdn

I have an Azure Media Service set up with a Premium subscription. I made an Android app which uses VideoView player and requests the multi-bitrate video files over HTTPS using the following format for asset links:

> https://example.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/c2234567-be1a-123c-ca25-e90bfca246da/1227_e3337f7-35ac-43e0-b55c-223e3333662.ism/QualityLevels(421811)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)

Until now, I had CDN integration disabled. This worked fine and I never had issues using HTTPS.

However, now I want to enable CDN integration with default settings. When this feature is enabled, it automatically attaches the media service subdomain as a custom domain under the CDN (in this case example.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net). From what I understand, this means I should be able to continue making requests from my Android app to the same URLs as before, except now it will direct those requests to the CDN instead of the media service.

However, what I'm not sure of is whether or not I'll still be able to call those URLs over HTTPS. I see that Azure has a feature for Custom Domains with HTTPS in the works but it doesn't appear to be available yet.

So does the ability to call media service asset URLs over HTTPS carry over after CDN integration, and especially if I'm using the default media service subdomain as my custom domain?

If not, what will happen to the HTTPS calls? Will they receive no response or will they just bypass the CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have no issues using HTTPS on CDN enabled Media Services Endpoints.
The Custom Domain HTTPS primarily refers to vanity urls like "blizz.com", which is not currently supported.